# Over-sampling when predicting a contionuous variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, imbalanced-learn, numerical, imbalanced-data

Lets say i am predicting house selling prices (continuous) and therefore have multiple independent variables (numerical and categorical). Is it common practice to balance the dataset when the categorical independent variables are imbalanced? Ratio not higher 1:100. Or do i only balance the data when the dependent variable is imbalanced?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually imbalanced data refers to imbalanced dependent variable, so are what the common data balancing techniques work for. As for the independent variables, I think it depends on whether it is critical to balance it or not.